# What were the plans for future thunderbirds episodes?

Tags: thunderbirds

The second series of Thunderbirds (the original 1960s series) was cut short at six episodes (see the below article) after the first series which had 26 episodes (because of the demand for a movie I believe) I was wondering if anyone knew what the plans were for the future episodes (ie plot, introduction of new characters etc.), if they exist out there somewhere.

> Cancellation Edit
>
> The Original plan could have been to have series 2 to have the same
>   number of episodes as the one before. But when Lew Grade played his
>   cards wrong when tying to syndicate the show in america. He thought
>   the money spent on the show was to much if it wasn't syndicated in
>   America. So he cancelled

Source: http://thunderbirds.wikia.com/wiki/Series_2

Comment: Not an answer (hence I'm posting this as a comment), but did you know about the two movies: [Thunderbirds Are Go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbirds_Are_Go) and [Thunderbird 6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbird_6)? I'm guessing these might have been at least influenced by draft scripts. Then there was the live action [Thunderbirds film](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbirds_(film)) (which I really liked, though it had poor reviews). Finally, did you hear about [Thunderbirds 2086](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbirds_2086)?! Worth a look!

Comment: @Wikis - thanks.  I was aware of all of those, although my understanding was that Anderson was told fairly suddenly to make a movie.  I would have thought that they'd have planned, or at least have had an idea for the future.

Comment: *Thunderbirds Are Go* was shot alongside the second series of *Thunderbirds*, so it seems unlikely that it would have raided other scripts. (That said, some of the models, and perhaps plot ideas, from TAG made their way to *Captain Scarlet*.) And apparently Anderson suggested the movie. Fanderson has a lot of detail, but sadly doesn’t say anything about extra scripts or plots:  http://www.fanderson.org.uk/prodguides/movies.html#Film%20Two

Comment: [ITV in the UK are now planning on a new series](http://www.itv.com/news/topic/thunderbirds/), by the looks of things with puppets still for 2016.

Comment: Can you add a link or something to back this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that quite simply the answer to this question is no - there were no plans for future episodes that we can access now with the sad departure of Mr Anderson (RIP) who may have had one or two ideas in mind that he never spoke of.